# Inheritance in JSON Config File in Java

Tags: java, json, api, rest, inheritance

I have an API which takes the details from a config file in JSON . eg

```
  "sections": {
    "Vehicles": ["Car ", "Bus",],
    "Air transport": ["Helicopter", "Aeroplanes "],
    
  },
  "sectionItems": {
     "Car": ["Small","4 seat","private"],
     "Bus": ["Big", "20 seat", "passenger", "etc"],
     "Helicopter": ["Blades", "straight", "etc"],
     "Aeroplane":["cargo ","wings ","etc"]
...
}
```

Now I want to change it according to my API . Lets say I need v1 and v2.
So there will be a base parent config file which will contain the common objects

```
  "sections": {
    "Vehicles": ["Car ", "Bus",],
    "Air transport": ["Helicopter", "Aeroplanes "],
    "C": ["a", "b", "c"],
  },
  "sectionItems": {
     "Car": ["Small","4 seat","private"],
    
     "Helicopter": ["Blades", "straight", "etc"],
     
...
}
```

*Bus and Aeroplanes is missing*

Two v1 and v2 config file that will contain the only respective changes that are required to avoid duplicates .

**V1**

```
  "sectionItems": {
     "Bus": ["20 seat" "etc"],
    
     "Aeroplane":["wings ","etc"]
     }
}
```

**V2**

```
  "sectionItems": {
     "Bus": ["Big", "20 seat", "passenger", "etc"],
     "Aeroplane":["cargo ","wings ","etc"]
}
}
```

How can i achieve this using ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a simple data format, you can use a more sophiscated format such as YAML (with YAML anchors) or HOCON (for Java: https://github.com/lightbend/config).

Or transform JSON into Java map and write some Java code.